# A detail movie in a new page- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want to do is when a specific movie is pressed it will open a new page where movie picture, overview, title and average score will be presented for that specific movie.

I'm using TMDB db and I have successfully made so that it displays Top_rated movies. My biggest question is, how do I pass the specific parameters of that movie (each movie has a specific id to it) to another method.

Here is my code so far -> MoviesComponent.dart:

```
   import React from "react";
const IMG_API="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/";

const Movie =({title, poster_path, backdrop_path, vote_average})=>
(

    <div className="movie">
        
        <img src={IMG_API+poster_path} alt={backdrop_path}/>
        <div className="info">
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <span>{vote_average}</span>
        </div>


    </div>
);



export default Movie;
```

And Movies.dart where its all shown (edited):

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Movie from './components/MovieComponent';
import Logo from './assets/chillax2.svg';
import MovieDetails from './MovieDetail';

//due to it being a demo project I will not safe keep the API
const SEARCH_API="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&query=";
const TOP_RATED_API="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&page=1"

function Movies() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [id, setID] = useState('');
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

useEffect(()=>{
  fetch(TOP_RATED_API)
  .then((res)=>res.json())
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    setMovies(data.results);
    setID(data.results)
  });

},[]);



const handleOnSubmit= (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault();


  if(setSearchTerm){
  fetch(SEARCH_API+searchTerm)
  .then((res)=>res.json())
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    setMovies(data.results);
  });

  setSearchTerm('');
}
} 

const handleOnChange= (e)=> {
  setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
}  
 

const details= Movies.filter((movie) => movie.id === id);
return(
  <>

  <header>   
  <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
  <img href="/" className="logo" src={Logo}></img>
  <div className="nav-bar-button">
    <a href="/Movies" className="film">Movies</a>
    <a href="/TVShows" >TV Shows</a>
  <input className="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Search"  value={searchTerm} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
  </div>
  </form>
  </header>

  <div className="container" onClick={MovieDetails(details)}>
    {movies.length && movies.map((movie)=>
    <Movie key={movie.id} {...movie} />)}
  </div> 
  </>
);
 
}

export default Movies;
```

Here is also MovieDetailsComponent.dart:

```
import React from "react";
const IMG_API="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/";

const MovieDetail =({title, poster_path, backdrop_path, vote_average, overview})=>
(
    <div className="movie">
        
        <img src={IMG_API+poster_path} alt={backdrop_path}/>
        <div className="info">
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <span>{vote_average}</span>
            <p>{overview}</p>
        </div>


    </div>
);


export default MovieDetail;
```

And MovieDetails.dart:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MovieDetail from './components/MovieDetailComponents';
import Logo from './assets/chillax2.svg';

//due to it being a demo project I will not safe keep the API
const SEARCH_API="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&query=";
const TOP_RATED_API="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&page=1"

function MovieDetails() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [id, setID] = useState('');


useEffect(()=>{
  fetch(TOP_RATED_API)
  .then((res)=>res.json())
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    setMovies(data.results);
  });

},[]);
 
return(
  <>

  <header>   
  <img href="/" className="logo" src={Logo}></img>
  <div className="nav-bar-button">
    <a href="/Movies" className="film">Movies</a>
    <a href="/TVShows" >TV Shows</a>
  </div>
  </header>

  <div>
    {movies.length && movies.map((movie)=>
    <MovieDetail key={movie.id} {...movie}/>)}
  </div> 
  </>
);
 
}

export default MovieDetails;
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MovieDetail from './components/MovieDetailComponents';
import Logo from './assets/chillax2.svg';

//due to it being a demo project I will not safe keep the API
const SEARCH_API="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&query=";
const TOP_RATED_API="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=89eef3426d167c3c8145a257ebe68357&page=1"

function MovieDetails() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [id, setID] = useState('');


useEffect(()=>{
  fetch(TOP_RATED_API)
  .then((res)=>res.json())
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    setMovies(data.results);
  });

},[]);
 
return(
  <>

  <header>   
  <img href="/" className="logo" src={Logo}></img>
  <div className="nav-bar-button">
    <a href="/Movies" className="film">Movies</a>
    <a href="/TVShows" >TV Shows</a>
  </div>
  </header>

  <div>
    {movies.length && movies.map((movie)=>
    <MovieDetail key={movie.id} {...movie}/>)}
  </div> 
  </>
);
 
}

export default MovieDetails;
```

Like I previously said, making a modal box isn't the hard part, what is troubling me is how do I pass those specific parameters (of the movie that I click on) to a function/object so I can use those details (title, picture, overview) in it.

Thanks in advance for all the tips and helpful comments. :D

Answer (score 0):

Make state for single movie. As soon as you click on some movie get it's id, filter from your movies list based on the id and pass that state to the pop up.

```
const [id, setID] = useState('');
```

This is your state for ID. Use onClik on each movie in the list and set ID. Then based on it filter your movies array.

```
Movies.filter((movie) => movie.id === id);
```

Either save the result of above filter in variable or state and pass it to your modal component.

Comment: Emmm, how should I do that. Ok making state is easy part for one movie: const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]); But how to pass the id of it?

Comment: I have updated my question, I'm not quite sure where to put those elements so can you guide me, also right now as the code is, it is displaying this error: TypeError: Movies.filter is not a function

Comment: I believe he wanted to write movies.filter (with a lowercase 'm') not Movies.filter. Reason: movies is the array we wanted to apply filter on and .filter is a function for arrays only so, fixing that will fix TypeError


Note: 
If 'id' is unique for each movie (as you said) it's better to use .find instead of .filter as .find will give you the exact object, from which you can use details (title, picture, .etc) instead of array (and it stops executing as soon as it matches)
Even better (for larger array) transform your array into object by id and use moviesMap[id] directly